# JSON parsing data not found after successful connection in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to swift. Trying to parse data from a page. Due to some reason the connection establishment is success but the data not going through. Please help me to solve the issue. here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var termsLabel: UILabel!

    let baseURL = "http://grandthecompany.com/admin/terms_api.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        getTermsData(url: baseURL)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    //MARK: - Networking
    /***************************************************************/

   func getTermsData(url: String) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {

                    print("Sucess! Got the Terms data")
                    let termsJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    self.updateTermsData(json: termsJSON)

                } else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    self.termsLabel.text = "Connection Issues"
                }
        }

    }


    //MARK: - JSON Parsing
    /***************************************************************/

    func updateTermsData(json : JSON) {

        if let termsResult = json[0].string{

            termsLabel.text = termsResult

        }else{
           termsLabel.text = "No data found"
        }


    }


}
```

[Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E733Y.png)

Comment: You are accessing the first element of json array. json[0]["terms"].string will give you term.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the first element of json array. `json[0]["terms"].string` will give you the term element.

```
func updateTermsData(json : JSON) {

    if let termsResult = json[0]["terms"].string{

        termsLabel.text = termsResult

    }else{
       termsLabel.text = "No data found"
    }

}
```